# Test Application Keys for Twilio Authy Client

Tags: python, django, rest, twilio, verification

I am using Python Client for Twilio Authy API (https://github.com/authy/authy-python). To create a new Connection Instance the following is used:

```
from authy.api import AuthyApiClient
authy_api = AuthyApiClient('#your_api_key')
```

For testing purposes, are test Application Keys available that do not necessarily send the OTP to phone but gives the appropriate responses?

Where or how do I get this test Application Key?

Comment: I don't think we have these any more. What do you need a test key like this for?

Comment: For carrying out tests without being charged.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend running tests against a live API (even with a test API key) because your tests would then rely on your network as well as the API itself. Instead, I recommend mocking the API response.

Comment: Okay, will consider that.